# How to plot x=-3|sin(y)| in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw the graph of x=-3|sin (y)| to produce a portion of the graph that looks like a letter E. Could you help?

Comment: with your reputation you should know, that at least a MWE is needed to help.

Comment: Could you provide code for a minimal working example of what you have got so far?  We need to know the context of your problem in order to advise on making a curve that meets your specific needs.

Comment: have you had a look at Chapter 75 "Creating Data Visualizations" of the PGF manual? If yes, what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) and plot it parametrically

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                ymin=-4,ymax=4,
      ]
      \addplot[ samples=200, domain=-pi:pi] ({-3*abs(sin(deg(x)))}, {x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?
 (to remove axes, just replace `school book axes` with `xy Cartesian`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
        \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data[format=function] {
        var y : interval [-pi:pi] samples 210;
        func x = -3*abs(sin(\value y r));
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry: I know it's a bad habit to answer these apparently "do-it-for-me" questions, but I wanted to learn how to do it (-;

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the curve 7pt thick and red?

Comment: Yes, thanks for doing that, @ebo.  You introduced me to a `tikz` library that I really need to study.